# What are the most auspicious times of the Jewish year for contributing money?

Tags: minhag, calendar, money, tzedakah-charity, chagim-holidays

What dates/months/seasons (or holidays) are considered most auspicious and/or customary for giving monetary gifts, such as tzedakah? I am aware from my own experience that Purim and erev Yom Kippur seem to be such times...maybe Chanukah, too. Are there any others?

Comment: now............

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Presumably to claim a tax deduction?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin (Or is it something special about 24 Adar?)

Comment: Nein Maavirin Al HaMitzvos, Mitzva Ba LeYado Al Tachmiztena (kind of Inyanei DeYoma)

Comment: Not enough for an answer, but I just read that on fast days, it is customary to give extra charity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is customary to pledge charity when saying *yizkor* (which is said on the last day of *Pesach* and *Shavuos* and on *Yom Kipur* and *Sh'mini Atzeres*) or "*Kel male*" (said anytime for specific persons, especially on or before a yahrzeit). (*P're M'gadim*, *MZ*, *OC* 284:2.)

There are requirements to give to the poor on *Purim* (*OC* 694) and before *Pesach* (*Rama*, *OC* 429:1). It's customary to do so (in the form of three halves of the prevailing currency, e.g. three half-dollar coins) just before Purim (*Kitzur SA* 141:5).

It's good to give charity before lighting *Shabas* candles (*Kitzur SA* 75:2), to increase charity during the ten days of repentance (130:1) and (especially to poor Torah scholars) on *Chanuka* (139:1), and to give to the poor on *erev Yom Kipur* (131:1).

Many have the custom of pledging charity when attending a *mitzva* meal, such as a wedding. (*Taame Haminhagim* 981.)

Many have the custom of pledging charity when receiving an honor, like an *aliya*, at the Torah scroll or in the synagogue. (*Taame Haminhagim*, footnote 5 to 835.)

Comment: Thanks. Since yizkor is always yomtov, does one make the pledge before or after? And does one make it then only if one is saying yizkor?

Comment: Also, do people have the custom to make general donations at Purim and 'before Pesach' or is it literally just for money to the poor? (apart from the actual mitzvos of wheat money and Purim matenas l'viyonim)

Comment: @SAH AFAIK _yizkor_ money is pledged (but of course not given) at _yizkor_ itself and primarily/only by those saying _yizkor_.

Comment: @SAH Wheat money and _matanos laevyonim_ are what I'm referring to in my answer.

Comment: Why wouldn't pledging money, with the intention to give it later, violate the laws of yomtov? (It would certainly violate the laws of Shabbos...) I realize people do this all the time; why is it allowed?

Comment: @SAH Fortunately, you can satisfy your curiosity without even asking a Mi Yodeya question: [it's already been asked for you](/q/8697).